# How to use array_push to multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php

I was wondering how to use array_push to multidimensional arrays?
I have a  multidimensional array, in which i'm trying to push more values from another array. The multidimensional you can see below.

```
$userList[] = array(
                        "aid" => $searchrow['aid'], 
                        "name" => $searchrow['name'],
                        "info" => $searchrow['info'],
                        "rental" => $searchrow['rental'],
                        "rentalfirm" => $searchrow['rental_firm'],
                        "acqprice" => $searchrow['acq_price'],
                        "renprice" => $searchrow['ren_price'],
                        "serial" => $searchrow['serial']); 

                        }
```

Second set of arrays:

```
mysql query... blaa blaa

    $assetInuseID[]=$searchrowinuse['asset_usage_id'];
        $inuse[]=$searchrowinuse['in_use'];
        $total[]=$searchrowinuse['total'];
```

What I'm tryin to accomplice is something like below.

```
$i = 0;

while(!empty($userList[$i][aid]))
{

   if($userList[$i][aid] == $assetInuseID[$i])
   {
   array_push($userList[$i][inUse], "$inuse[$i]");
   array_push($userList[$i][total], "$total[$i]");
   }
  $i ++;

}
```

So, I want to create: inUse- and total-cells in the allready existing $userList[][] and populate them with with the allready existing values of $total[$i] and $inuse[$i] when the $userList[$i][aid] matches $assetInuseID[$i].

I hope someone understands me, my explanation was a little bit confusing...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following,

> $userList[$i]["inUse"] = "$inuse[$i]";

Remember `array_push` — Push one or more elements onto the end of array and not create an index.